# What exactly does AddTeX2Eps do and how does one use it?

Tags: export, packages, latex

What exactly is Janko Slavic's addon package [AddTeX2Eps](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/6193/) supposed to do, and exactly how does one get it to work?

I do understand it's supposed to allow one to use TeX `psfrag` processing upon a Mathematica-generated graphic, but I cannot discern from the meager docs what's going on. And I can't get the supplied sample notebook `AddTeX2Eps-Example` to process correctly. When I evaluate the notebook, from the `EpsExport` command there I get a long list of errors starting with `OpenRead::noopen : canot open EpsExport.ps`

(So I never get to the point of being able to use the exported file from within LaTeX where, I presume, psfrag is going to process it.)

Comment: May we assume that you have followed all instructions in the Readme file?

Comment: Yes, I followed the instructions in the readme file -- except that I put the `AddTeX2Eps` folder in `$UserAddOnsDirectory/Applications`